# Python string trimming

Tags: python, regex, string, trim

I have a string in python, which is in this format:

```
[NUMBER][OPERATOR][NUMBER][UNNEEDED JUNK]
```

e.g.:

```
5+5.[)]1
```

How could I trim that down to just `5+5`?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention, basically, you just need to look for the first non-numeric character after the operator, and crop everything (starting at that point) off.

Comment: Could you please explicit a little bit more the boundary cases, what I mean is this could be easily solved by `str = str[:5]` but that probably doesn't apply to all cases

Comment: Right... the numbers could be any amount of digits (no decimals), but the operator will always be +

Comment: @a sandwich, I misread what was being asked. Deleted my comment after I realized it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple regular expression:

```
import re

s = "5+5.[)]1"
s = re.search("\d+\+\d+", s).group()
print(s) # 5+5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
re.search(r'\d+.\d+','123+55.[)]1').group()
```

This should work.

Comment: `re` being the string in question?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins - [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) is the python regular expression module.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: no re is the name of the module you imported, stands for regex. the string is this:`r'\d+.\d+','123+55.[)]1'`

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Both of the answers are correct but only because you clarified that no decimals`(floats). This is correct for what you asked but won't work for `123+5.5.[)]1` if `123+5.5` is the number you are asking.

Comment: the string to search is missing.

Comment: i upp'ed this because this one can handle the any single operator.  otherwise you can catch any longer operator with `^\d` or [+-*/] to catch all simple operators.

Comment: @Dr.J: Read the comments: `but the operator will always be +`

Comment: then `[+-]` should suffice. or `.` or `[^\d]`, but hey, nothing wrong with being able to expand the question!

Comment: Dr.J: In fact, that is wrong. In regular expressions stuff like that will create false matches like 5a3. Keep it as tight as possible.